# tkinter can't .get() the text variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

def corequiz():
    Guess.get()
    global Guess_num
    Guess_num = Guess_num + 1
    if song == Guess:
        print("congratulations the song was " + song)
        if Guess_num == 1:
            print("well done " + name + " you guessed it on your first try")
            User_score = User_score + 3
            print(name + " your points are " + str(User_score))
        elif Guess_num == 2:
            print("well " + name + " you did it on your second try")
            User_score = User_score + 1
        else:
            print("you failed to answer the question")
            print("your current points are " + str(User_score))
    else:
        print("wrong")

def Quiz(name,User_score,artist,song):
            root = Tk()
            root.title("game")
            root.geometry("720x500+0+0")
            heading = Label(root, text="welcome to the quiz game",font=("arial",24,"bold"),fg = "black").pack()
            tip = Label(root, text=("this song is by " + artist + " and the first few letters of the song is: " + song[0] + song[1]),font=("italics",10,"normal"),fg = "black").place(x=10,y=50)
            usernameenter = heading = Label(root, text="enter your guess of the song: ",font = ("arial",11,"bold"),fg="black").place(x=10,y=100)
            Guess = StringVar()
            entry_box2 = Entry(root, textvariable= Guess,width=80,bg="light blue").place(x=222,y=105)
            entryguess = Button(root, text="Submit",width=30, height=3,bg="lightblue",command=corequiz).place(x=250,y=200)
            root.mainloop()

#theses are example variables
global Guess_num                            
Guess_num = 0
global song                            
song = "shake it off"                            
global artist                            
artist = "Taylor swift"                            
global User_score                            
User_score = 1                            
global name                           
name = "gamer"                            
Quiz(name,User_score,artist,song)
```

i am new at tkinter.

i can't get this code to get the Guess to pass to corequiz subroutine.

how can i get guess.get() to actually get the variable from the entry box when you click the button that guess to subroutine corequiz.

i have tried making global variables and making it not inside a subroutine. But none of that works Guess just outputs Guess is not defined from Guess.get().

this code is for my programming project i am doing. Which is gui song quiz: if user get it right first time its 3 point, second 1 point and third time close the program. This is running on python 3.7

Comment: `Guess` is a local variable that exists only inside the `Quiz()` function. You need to define it at the module-level outside of any any functions. Also not that the `pack()` and `place()` methods don't return anything, so your code is assigning `None` to variables like `heading`, `entry_box2`, etc.

Comment: thank you i changed so the gui entry box_2 is not in subroutine and added a subroutine to retrieve using get(), And it works now.

Comment: hitime: That's good to hear...and you're welcome.